# remove responsive feature from opencart 2.0.3 themes

Tags: opencart2.x

I want to remove responsive feature[I want to have same view on desktop and mobile device] from my Opencart's theme(default theme).I use Opencart version 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

For Responsive it needs View port Meta,
So Remove View Port Meta from header file

```
// catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl:10

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: I did same but don't get any result.I think that have some problem with bootstrap

Comment: give it a try on device not on browser
it works fine on mine